# Does any way to get the last inserted values in each days

Tags: mysql, postgresql

```
id             date        calls
5   2015-02-17 01:06:01       1
6   2015-02-17 11:07:01       2
7   2015-02-17 23:06:01       3
8   2015-02-18 03:07:01       1
9   2015-02-18 09:06:01       2
10  2015-02-18 17:07:01       3
11  2015-02-18 22:06:01       4
12  2015-02-19 01:07:01       1
13  2015-02-19 08:06:01       2
14  2015-02-19 18:07:01       3
15  2015-02-19 23:06:01       4
```

my table structure is like this and I need to calculate the sum of call in each days. In this table, you can see that, the last call in feb 17 was at 23:06:01 and call count was 3. In feb 18 was at 22:06:01 and call count was 4. Can I get the sum of all this last call counts of each day.

Comment: The answer is yes, but have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Looks like an aggregation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: Hi christain, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67d3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to determine which rows to sum (the ones matching the last call for each date, using MySQL it would be:

```
select sum(calls) sum_last_calls
from your_table
where `date` in (
    select max(date) max_date 
    from your_table 
    group by date(`date`)
    )
```

This query will return `11` as the sum (from 3+4+4).

The `date()` function used in the subquery is specific to your database and might need to be changed according to your specific database syntax - the point is that it should return the date without time (it could be `date::date` (Postgresql) or `cast(date as date)` (MSSQL and others)).

Sample SQL Fiddle for [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67d3/1) and [Postgresql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93097/2)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I need to take calls between 2 dates. Is it possible?

Comment: @RoginThomas You need to use `group by` in the subquery like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67d3/10

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql version:

```
select sum(calls) as calls
from (
    select max(calls) as calls
    from t
    where date::date between '2015-02-17' and '2015-02-19'
    group by date::date
) s
```